# Magento 2 Products don't show after save

Tags: caching, redis, magento2.4

I have magento 2.4.2 and i have installed varnish and redis.
When i make a product and set it's categories note that some categories have the same name ex(musical instrument > bass  and new arrivals > musical instrument) after i save the changes the product doesn't show
in the frontend. Only after removing one category and saving the product then putting the category back again and clearing the cache the product shows up.

I tried disableling redis and tried again with another product but i got the same result.